# How to notate extended vocal techniques (i.e. inhaling)?

Tags: notation, voice

While the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_vocal_technique) indicates many types of extended vocal techniques, their notations are not available.

Despite hearing such effects in modern pieces, I've never had the chance of knowing how they are notated. I only know that ghost notes represent speech rather than singing, and the ghost notes and the mezza voce notation indicate a whisper-like sound.

Let's say, **how should we notate that a part should be sung by inhaling**, whispering, growling or screaming?

Are there any signs for this? Should the techniques be just written in words as an indication? Is there a guide or notation manual that tells how to notate such techniques?

Comment: Check out some scores. Off the top of my head, Berio's Sequenza for Voice could be instructive. Here's a link to a YouTube recording of it which shows the score: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DGovCafPQAE

Comment: Check out Kurt Stone's *20th Century Notation* - it has a wonderfully comprehensive section on notating various vocal effects.

Answer (score 4):

In general, extended vocal techniques like these are indicated via a change of notehead along with a textual description of the desired effect (i.e. "whispered", "screamed", etc). The specifics of this may vary in practice, depending on the particular needs of the piece: if there are only a few isolated effects needed, for example, they could all be marked with an "x" notehead and given a short text note inline at each occurrence; but in a composition with multiple effects used frequently and in close proximity, each effect could be given a distinct notehead with a legend given at the start of the piece or in a preface, describing the desired techniques corresponding with each type of notehead. Above all, the primary concern is clarity and understandability by the performer, so the composer/engraver can have a lot of latitude in how to achieve that.

There is also specialized notation that can be used for inhalation/exhalation that doesn't really apply to other vocal techniques. This is described in the excellent notation reference *[Behind Bars](http://www.behindbarsnotation.co.uk/)*, by Elaine Gould:

> An arrow placed above a note may indicate audible inhalation and exhalation while singing; a backward arrow indicates inhaling, and a forward arrow indicates exhaling:
>
> [image: inhaling/exhaling]